# How can I update a React state with an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have am trying to update a state in a React component using axios to pass the new state into another component. This is my code below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      list: [],
      data: []
    }

    this.dataById = this.dataById.bind(this);
  }

  dataById(e) {
    this.setState({ idToGet: e.target.value});
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(e.target.value))) {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/message/${e.target.value}`)
        .then(res => {
          const data = res.data;
          this.setState({ data });
        });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">React App</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
          <List data={this.state.data} dataById={this.dataById}/> 
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I tried to update the state using axios, I got an error that said "Objects are not valid as a React child". I checked that I binded the `dataById` function.

However, I want to use the object that I get back from `axios` and pass that object into my `List` component.

How should I accomplish this? Is there a way to bypass the error and still pass the object into my `List` component?

Edit: Here is the `List` component

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ data, dataById }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12">
          <div className="chat">
            <div className="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-3">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter id"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={dataById}
                onKeyDown={dataById}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>{data}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you add your `<List/>` render function. The error you're getting occurs when you try to directly render an object. Just passing it to the list as a prop won't cause any issues

Comment: @emvo Can you post the `List` component and also wrap the `List` inside `{ <List /> }` and see.

Comment: Looks like the issue is not with axios but with List render()

Comment: so the axios response is an array or its an object ? can you post the axios response , res.data ?

Comment: @sridharreddy I updated the post with my List component.

Answer (score 0):

"Objects are not valid as a React child"

You are trying to render an object `<div>{data}</div>`.

try `<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>`